# ImageView positioned on an imageView

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout

Hello I am developing an android application in java under android studio and I want my second image to be positioned at 50% of the height and 20% of the width (for example) of the first image and not the parent, so that the ratio of image overlay is respected with different sizes of screen. I can't find how to do it, do you have an idea?

This is the activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Your Data" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tetx"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/iut" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/marker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/m2" />



</LinearLayout>
```

I put the xml file but I plan to modify the percentages later in MainActivity.java so it's not disturbing if you have an idea that goes through java code.

Comment: I would recommend a ConstraintLayout that would give the flexibility to do this.

Comment: I've been trying since this morning but even with a constraintlayout I can't, can you give me an example?

Comment: Yeah let me build one real quick. If you are new to android I would also suggest Jetpack Compose. I find it much easier but I will make you an answer in both.